# Losing attributes of NSAttributedString between drag and drop

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Dragging between UICollectionView and another UIView, I get the NSAttributedString but without the .font attribute.

The drop function:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    session.loadObjects(ofClass: NSAttributedString.self, completion: { providers in
        let dropPoint = session.location(in: self)
        for attributedString in providers as? [NSAttributedString] ?? [] {
            \\ gets here
            for attr in attributedString.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) {

                print(attr.key, attr.value) // no attributes to print

            }
        }
    })
}
```

And the drag function:

```
func dragItemFor(indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]{
    if let cell = eiCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? EiCollactionViewCell {
        if let attributedString = cell.label.attributedText {
            for attr in attributedString.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) {
                print("pre drag vc: ",attr.key, attr.value)// prints the font 
            }
            let dragItem =  UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider(object:  attributedString))
            dragItem.localObject = attributedString
            return [dragItem]
        }
    }
    return []
}
```

Comment: the print out from the drag side is:  
pre drag vc:  NSAttributedStringKey(_rawValue: NSFont) <UICTFont: 0x7fb61ad3dd50> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 53.00pt

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your attributed string has no attributes to *start* with. `.SFUIDisplay` is not a font value. It's just a way of saying "the default". If you want a font, you need to *set* a font.

Comment: what I want to get is the size of the font which is custom. I set a .font to the attributedString. UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .title1).scaledFont(for: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:  .body).withSize(50.0))